# dotdotdot plugin together with Knockout remove content

Tags: knockout.js, dotdotdot

I has knockout custom binding and use "dotdotdot" into it.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dotdotdot =
{
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      $(element).text(value);
      setTimeout(function () {
          $(element).dotdotdot({ wrap: 'letter', fallbackToLetter: 'letter', 
          watch: 'window' });
          }, 300);
      },
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      $(element).text(value);
      setTimeout(function () {
      $(element).dotdotdot({ wrap: 'letter', fallbackToLetter: 'letter', 
      watch: 'window' });
         }, 300);
      }
};
```

I use this binding like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
 ....
  <td>
     <span data-bind="dotdotdot: TeamMemberName ">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

where self.TeamMemberName = ko.observable(data.TeamMemberName);

After page loaded "dotdotdot" completely removes all content and column becomes empty. I try to use "height" property with span, but it doesn't work. What I do wrong?

Comment: What version of dotdotdot are you using? I don't see support for the options you're passing to it in the latest version. There's no "wrap" or "fallbackToLetter" that I can find.

Comment: You don't need to bind `$(element).dotdotdot()` inside `update`.

Comment: @JasonSpake, I use version 1.8.1

Comment: @adiga, I remove dotdotdot from update function, so it contains only this: var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
      $(element).text(value); .   RESULT - https://www.screencast.com/t/sXQgprNN. Only long string is displayed. Short strings are hidden. I change span to div and result becomes - https://www.screencast.com/t/XEXZZ4jHl . It displays  data but it is not truncated. Also, o try to use "height" property to div, but content is removing.

Comment: @JasonSpake, also I removed all options so calling is $(element).dotdotdot({}).

Comment: @Andrey-T can you create a fiddle? [I can't get the dotodotdot to work](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/v161fkzn/4/)

Comment: I created the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/defmindat/tj8ezdmm/4/ . It works but only with version 2.0.1. I have noticed that dotdotdot with version > 2.0.1 not working. Also if you use span instead of div then content is removed. And you need have height restrictions (height: ...) to div because height restrictions of <td> is not working